# Is it a good practice to store data in nosql database like this?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

So basically I'am building a todo app with vue.js + firestore.

In my db there is the todos collection which has some fields (doesn't matter) and the userId field.

If I create a TODO with user A, it saves the A user's ID to the userID field in the todos collection.
If I create a TODO with user B, it saves the B user's ID to the userID field in the todos collection.
.
and so on
.
.

So if I log in with differend users, it shows me each users **todos** based on the **userId** field in the **todos** collection.

**Now, is this a good practice to link data to users like this in the nosql world ?**

Comment: What is mean by good practice ? If your database structure is in proper Manner then it won't cause problem. In nosql you can relate document with their id's

Comment: for example If an app has 10k+ documents in collection, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Yes, Even if you have 10k+ document and your database structure is perfect then you can do what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Yes, Even if you have 10k+ document and your database structure is perfect then you can do what you want - @Ashish